# Ruby-on-Rails: ActiveAdmin SuperClass Mismatch TypeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm just trying to install ActiveAdmin. Seems pretty straightforward.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/create-beautiful-administration-interfaces-with-active-admin/

But when I get to rails generate active_admin:install

I get:

```
$ rails generate active_admin:install
/home/user/active_admin/config/application.rb:13:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>': superclass mismatch for class Application (TypeError)
from /home/user/active_admin/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Can't seem to find anyone else with this problem. I even deleted active_admin and started the whole thing again from scratch... no dice.

Comment: Your project name is ActiveAdmin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to rename your application, it cannot be named `active_admin`.

Comment: Ok. How do I rename the application? (Sorry... kind of a ruby newbie.)

Comment: This is probably a lot more than you bargained for... But I downloaded rename, I tried to reinstall it as per it's instructions: rails plugin install git@github.com:get/Rename.git That didn't work. So instead I did rails plugin new Rename. That worked but rails g rename_to Acid_Admin
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options *Those are rename's instructions but it didn't work.

Comment: Would it be easier if I just delete the directory and start from scratch? And at what point of the instructions did they set me on the wrong path? http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/create-beautiful-administration-interfaces-with-active-admin/

Comment: @mysticcola, the problem is that they tell you to run `rails new active_admin`, but you cannot use that app name. Just do something like `rails new my_active_admin`

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to help me! Both that guide and the official documentation are wrong... I don't understand how I'm the only one who had this problem. Anyway I deleted the project, made a new one with a different name, and everything installed without a hitch. Thanks again!

Comment: i had the same problem :/

Comment: Just go into config/application.rb and rename the module. which in your case will be called ActiveAdmin. Just call it something else